# Redirect a form to different modal dialog VB.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, bootstrap-modal, html-helper

I have a form with two submit buttons. Both buttons will send the form to the same controller but different modal dialog. This is my code. I try to add `onclick="location.href='#modal1';"` but it does not direct
me to the dialog.

```
<form Class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" id="myform" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
    <div Class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="day" id="day" Class="form-control">
        <input type="text" name="staff" id="staff" Class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div Class="form-group">
        //this button will redirect to #modal1
        <button type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Yes</button>
        //this button will redirect to #modal2
        <button type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">No</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I try to use this. But there isan error said day and staff are not declared.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Index", "Home", Nothing, Nothing, "modal1", New With {.day = Day(), .staff = staff}, New With {.class = "btn"})
```

Comment: What do you mean _direct me to the dialog_? You submit buttons post to a `Index()` method. What is the code in that controller method? And your using buttons without any `name` attribute so you could not distinguish which button was clicked anyway.

Comment: I used this before`action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")#modal1"` so the modal will popup automatically.

Comment: Not clear what you asking. Your buttons submit your form to the `Index()` POST method. Its the code in that method that does the redirect. But I suspect you don't understand the terminology and you want to go to a bookmark on the existing page, not make a redirect? You need to edit your question and explain what your trying to do.

Comment: Yes it submit the form to Index(). But I have two buttons in which both buttons submit the form to Index(). But first button will open modal1 after submit while  second button will open modal2 after refresh